# nServiceBus and Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, nservicebus

Is there a possiblity to integrate a CF application into an nServiceBus architecture? Or are there any alternatives to nServiceBus with support for Compact Framework?

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of the Compact Framework, it has restrictions around reflection that could make it difficult to host the NServiceBus libraries there. You might be better off having it just call a web service that calls into NServiceBus.